# Javascript validation inside gridview cell

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, databound

I have a single entry master with country name in a gridview . I have to edit the data in a grid view in asp.net c#.  I want to validate the textbox inside edit template to see if the user enters invalid characters. I want to validate that using simple javascript code.

I tried [a-zA_Z] in regular expression validator...it is causing slow down in my app. so i am prefering JS.

I tried to get the value of client id using row data bound event in c# but it is interrupting the work flow of the program. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use the ASP.NET Validators to test this? It will apply both serverside and clientside checks on the data.

A reference URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx